# Calling asp.net server function using jquery ajax

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Am basically new to jquery. I have a function in aspx code bihind. I need to call it in a button click from aspx page using jquery. The server side function takes no arguement and returns no data. 
The function the code behind is :

```
[WebMethod]
    public void BindTreeview()
    {
        TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo RootDir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\ClientDocuments\Ford Retail Ltd\");
        // output the directory into a node
        TreeNode RootNode = OutputDirectory(RootDir, null);
        // add the output to the tree

        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(RootNode);
        //TreeView1.SelectedValue = hdnSelectedNode.Value;
        if (hdnSelectedNode.Value != string.Empty)
        {
            TreeView1.CollapseAll();
            TreeNode searchNode = TreeView1.FindNode("Electricity");
            if (searchNode != null)
                searchNode.Expand();
        }
    }
```

aspx jquery is

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btnNewFolder').click(function () {
           // alert('Clicked');

            $.ajax({
                url: 'Default.aspx/BindTreeview',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function () {
                    alert(1);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("The call to the server side failed. " + result.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

When i run appln am getting alert on result.responseText. Where am i getting wrong? Quick response will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Did you check the server side method was called by using breakpoint?

Comment: Yes. The breakpoint didnt hit. Rather it alerted the error with responseText

Answer (score 0):

mark your method as static

```
public static void BindTreeview()
```

Comment: You may want to explain why. Especially why webmethods have to be static.